# Trello API: Search for list

Tags: api, trello

I am using the path: '[/1/search/](https://trello.com/docs/api/search/)' to search for items in a Trello board.

According to the documentation, the only **modelTypes** that this will return are:

`[ 'actions', 'cards', 'boards', 'organizations', 'members' ]`

I would like to conduct a search for **lists**, is this possible in the current version of the API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's currently supported.

But, you could use `GET /1/boards/[board_id]/lists` to get all lists and then perform search from there. You would have to know the Board id though.

https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board#get-1-boards-board-id-lists